# The Select method in Telerik grid

Tags: telerik

What is the select() in ajax/server binding in the grid in telerik for?

I tried selecting row/column in the grid, it's not being called. When is it called?

Comment: can you post up some of your code?

Comment: @BrianGarson I figured it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Select method is for getting the data for filling the grid.